# Block Jenkins job until a certain resource is available

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, integration-testing

When using Jenkins as an integration server, some of my tests require the availability of external resources like an MySQL database server. Is it possible to block a job until such a resource is available?

The only workaround I can think of is using a periodically executed upstream job which checks for service availability which is kinda smelly.

Comment: How will you determine whether the resource is available? Is the database used only by Jenkins?

Comment: The database is only used by Jenkins. A simple test query would be enough in order to determine if a resource is available. Background: the external resources are not on the same host as Jenkins but virtual machines which will be rebuild from time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several plugins that allow resource management:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Exclusion-Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/External+Resource+Dispatcher

Some block the job from executing, others have the job "wait" for the resource (while job is running).